# How to search in the text in Html widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following task. The screen displays the text that I receive using the API in json format. This text is string containing HTML-format body. For displaying I use the flutter_html library and the Html() widget.

```
Html(
   data: """here is my string value with html content""",             
),
```

I want to implement a searching by words in text that is displayed in this widget. How can this be done? (For searching I have a textFormField on this screen)

Comment: By search, you mean to find the word written in the text field and highlighting it in the html? if so, you can replace the word in the html with a wrapping tag with background attribute, the html would render it in another color. If I understood correctly please mention, so I post an example answer.

Comment: @M.MahdiNabiollahi Yes, that's exactly what I mean. How can I replace the word in the HTML with a wrapping tag with background attribute using flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Base knowledge

To approach this, we should know that in html, `<mark>` tag would show the string highlighted (further explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_mark.asp)).
And I used [`flutter_html: ^3.0.0-beta.2`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html/versions/3.0.0-beta.2) for this sample.

#### What to do

So we have 2 strings, one is the main constant string which is not updated, and the other one is the source of the html and can be updated to show the found words.

```dart
static const _htmlBase = 'This is a sample html text which we are using the search function on.';
```

The other one is in the stateful widget. We also have the `TextEditingController` here.

```dart
...
class _HtmlFinderPageState extends State<HtmlFinderPage> {
  final TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();
  String _htmlBody = _htmlBase;
  ...
}
...
```

This is the `Column` containing the TextField widget and Html widget for our usecase:

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    TextField(
      controller: _searchController,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        suffixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.search,
        ),
        hintText: 'find',
      ),
      onChanged: _findTheValue,
    ),
    const SizedBox(height: 12),
    Html(
      data: '''
      <html>
        <body>
          $_htmlBody
        </body>
      </html>
      ''',
    )
  ],
),
```

The `_findTheValue()` function, replaces all found values in `_htmlBase` string with the same value with wrapped `<mark>` tag, and updates the `_htmlBody`.

```dart
void _findTheValue(value) {
  if (value.isNotEmpty) {
    setState(() {
      _htmlBody = _htmlBase.replaceAll(value, '<mark>$value</mark>');
    });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      _htmlBody = _htmlBase;
    });
  }
}
```

Now when we run this, we have a html containing the text, and a search field on top of it. When we type in the field, our query is found the text and gets highlighted.

#### Output

[image: output img]

#### Full code

This is the full code of Html finder page:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';

const _htmlBase = 'This is a sample html text which we are using the search function on.';

class HtmlFinderPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HtmlFinderPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HtmlFinderPage> createState() => _HtmlFinderPageState();
}

class _HtmlFinderPageState extends State<HtmlFinderPage> {
  final TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();
  String _htmlBody = _htmlBase;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: const Text('Html Finder'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                controller: _searchController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  suffixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                  ),
                  hintText: 'find',
                ),
                onChanged: _findTheValue,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 12),
              Html(
                data: '''
                <html>
                  <body>
                    $_htmlBody
                  </body>
                </html>
                ''',
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _findTheValue(value) {
    if (value.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        _htmlBody = _htmlBase.replaceAll(value, '<mark>$value</mark>');
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _htmlBody = _htmlBase;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _searchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

#### Full Project code on GitHub

if you would like to just run and test the code, you could check out the [full project](https://github.com/mahdinba97/flutter-samples/tree/main/html_finder)